# udev - change event from udev_device_get_action

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, udev, linux-device-driver

I am monitoring the events of all devices connected to the host.
Linux has udev daemon , which listens to all the device specific events such as online, offline, add, remove and **change**.

I use a function provided by linux **udev_device_get_action**, which is used to get the events / actions on that device.

On my machine, I am continuously getting **change events** returned from this function in my code's variable. [It returns the character pointer]

I checked the linux code for function **udev_device_get_action**, it just returns the **action** from the udev device structure.

```
UDEV_EXPORT const char *udev_device_get_action(struct udev_device *udev_device)
{
        if (udev_device == NULL)
                return NULL;
        return udev_device->action;
}
```

So, how can i know, where exactly those change events are coming from ??

Answer (score 1):

uevents are generated by the kernel itself (that is, by kernel drivers).

udev receives them over [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html), using the family NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT, group 1. It then adds various extra fields from rules & hwdb, and re-broadcasts the extended uevents to kobject-uevent group 2, where libudev finally receives them.

It is possible to trigger uevents manually (e.g. by writing "add" or "change" to a given device's `/sys/…/uevent` file), but that's usually not done, except when using "udevadm trigger".

Comment: But what is the meaning of CHANGE_EVENTS which i am getting  a lot from udevd..?

In my driver, i have taken care of ADD, REMOVE, ONLINE, OFFLINE events of UDEV for devices, but i am not getting purpose rather behaviour behind listening to CHANGE_EVENTS.

What is the cause for this and what would be use of it for any block-driver.?